# Error Saving Item (Invalid Name) in PHP

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I am using the Zoo CCK and have fiddled with the code long enough to get it to look like I want it to look.  However, when I submit the item I receive an error (in the title) that I cannot figure out.

To be less confusing, I should mention that the edit I made to the file was to add the parts for $message and any related code identifying it.

Any help would be appreciated.  Here is the file code below:

**ERROR:** Error Saving Item (Invalid Name)

```
<?php

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// register ElementOption class
App::getInstance('zoo')->loader->register('ElementOption', 'elements:option/option.php');
// register ElementRepeatable class
App::getInstance('zoo')->loader->register('ElementRepeatable', 'elements:repeatable/repeatable.php');
/*
Class: ElementSelect
    The select element class
*/

class ElementMessage extends ElementOption implements iSubmittable  {

/*
   Function: edit
       Renders the edit form field.

   Returns:
       String - html
*/
public function edit(){

    $this->app->document->addStylesheet('elements:message/assets/css/submission.css');
    // init vars
    $options_from_config = $this->config->get('option', array());
    $multiple            = $this->config->get('multiple');
    $default             = $this->config->get('default');
    $name                = $this->config->get('name');
    $message         = $this->get('message');

    if (count($options_from_config)) {

        // set default, if item is new
        if ($default != '' && $this->_item != null && $this->_item->id == 0) {
            $this->set('option', $default);
        }

        $options = array();
        if (!$multiple) {
            $options[] = $this->app->html->_('select.option', '', '-' . JText::sprintf('Select %s', $name) . '-');
        }
        foreach ($options_from_config as $option) {
            $options[] = $this->app->html->_('select.option', $option['value'], $option['name']);
        }

        $style = $multiple ? 'multiple="multiple" size="5"' : '';

        $html[] = $this->app->html->_('select.genericlist', $options, $this->getControlName('option', true), $style, 'value', 'text', $this->get('option', array()));
        $html[] = $this->app->html->_('control.text', $this->getControlName('Message'), $this->get('message'), 'name="message" size="30" maxlength="255" placeholder="'.JText::_('Message').'"');

        // workaround: if nothing is selected, the element is still being transfered
        $html[] = '<input type="hidden" name="'.$this->getControlName('select').'" value="1" />';

        return implode("\n", $html);
    }

    return JText::_("There are no options to choose from.");
}
public function hasValue($params = array()) {

    $message = $this->get('message');
    return !empty($message);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing:

```
$message         = $this->get('message');
```

to

```
$message         = $this->config->get('message');
```

Comment: Hi.  I changed both instances and tested them and I still have the same error.  I then changed only one of each and it still gave the same error.